# Updating react/redux state from inside a submit handler function

Tags: arrays, reactjs, redux, setstate, onsubmit

I'm currently working on a poll app which is supposed to sequentially render a list of questions and post answers to the server. I have no problem handling answers but looping through questions gave me some trouble.

Here is a flow of my code:

PollContainer.js - component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import Question from './Questions/Question';
import { pushAnswers } from '../../actions/answers';
import { incrementCounter } from '../../actions/utils';
import Thanks from './Thanks'


const PollContainer = () => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const questions = useSelector(state => state.questions); // an array of questions


// a counter redux state which should increment at every click of 'submit' inside a question

    const utils = useSelector(state => state.utils); 
    let activeQuestion = questions[utils.counter]; 


// function passed as a prop to a singular Question component to handle submit of an answer

    const pushSingleAnswer = (answer) => {
        let answersUpdate = state.answers;
        answersUpdate.push(answer);
        console.log(`counter:${utils.counter}`) // logs 0 everytime I click submit, while redux dev tools show that utils.counter increments at every click

        if (utils.counter < questions.length ) {
            setState({...state, answers: answersUpdate, activeQuestion: activeQuestion});
            dispatch(incrementCounter());
        } else{
            dispatch(pushAnswers(state.answers));
            setState({...state, isFinished: true});
        }
    };
         
    const [state, setState] = useState({ 
        isFinished: false,
        activeQuestion: questions[0],
        answers: [],
        pushSingleAnswer
         })

    return (
        (utils.isLoading) ? (
            <h1>Loading questions...</h1>
        ) : (
        <div>
            
            {(!state.isFinished && <Question { ...state }/>)}

            {(state.isFinished && <Thanks/>)} 

        </div>
    ))
}

export default PollContainer;
```

incrementCounter action:

```
import * as types from "./types";


export const incrementCounter = () => {
    return {
       type: types.INCREMENT_COUNTER,
    }
}
```

utils.js - reducer

```
// reducer handles what to do on the news report (action)

import * as types from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    isLoading: false,
    error: null,
    counter: 0
}

export default (utils = initialState, action) => {


    switch(action.type){ 

        case types.LOADING_DATA:
            return {...utils, isLoading: true};

        case types.DATA_LOADED:
            return {...utils, isLoading: false};

        case types.ACTION_FAILED:
            return {...utils, error: action.error};

        case types.INCREMENT_COUNTER:
            return {...utils, counter: utils.counter + 1} // here is the incrementing part

        default:
            return utils;
         
    }
}
```

`utils.counter` that is passed to `pushSingleAnswer` function doesn't increment, however redux dev tools tells me it does increase every time I click `submit` in a `Question` component. Because of that it doesn't render next questions. The submit handler in `Question` component is simply this:

```
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        props.pushSingleAnswer(state);
    };
```

I also tried with:

```
         useEffect(() => {
            dispatch(incrementCounter())},
            [state.answers]
        );
```

expecting it'll increment every time there's an update to `state.answers` but it doesn't work either. Morover the `counter` in redux-dev-tools doesn't increment either.

I'd be very grateful for any suggestions, this is my first serious react-redux project and I really enjoy working with these technologies. However I do not quite understand how react decides to render stuff on change of state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

1. You are closing over the initial `counter` state in the `pushSingleAnswer` callback stored in state and passed to `Question` component.
2. You are mutating your state object in the handler.

Code:

```
const pushSingleAnswer = (answer) => {
  let answersUpdate = state.answers; // <-- save state reference
  answersUpdate.push(answer); // <-- state mutation
  console.log(`counter:${utils.counter}`) // <-- initial value closed in scope

  if (utils.counter < questions.length ) {
    setState({
      ...state, // <-- persists closed over callback/counter value
      answers: answersUpdate,
      activeQuestion: activeQuestion,
    });
    dispatch(incrementCounter());
  } else{
    dispatch(pushAnswers(state.answers));
    setState({ ...state, isFinished: true });
  }
};

const [state, setState] = useState({ 
  isFinished: false,
  activeQuestion: questions[0],
  answers: [],
  pushSingleAnswer // <-- closed over in initial state
});

{(!state.isFinished && <Question { ...state }/>)} // <-- stale state passed
```

## Solution

Don't store the callback in state and use functional state updates.

```
const pushSingleAnswer = (answer) => {
  console.log(`counter:${utils.counter}`) // <-- value from current render cycle

  if (utils.counter < questions.length ) {
    setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState, // <-- copy previous state
      answers: [
        ...prevState.answers, // <-- copy previous answers array
        answer // <-- add new answer
      ],
      activeQuestion,
    }));
    dispatch(incrementCounter());
  } else{
    dispatch(pushAnswers(state.answers));
    setState({ ...state, isFinished: true });
  }
};

const [state, setState] = useState({ 
  isFinished: false,
  activeQuestion: questions[0],
  answers: [],
});

{!state.isFinished && (
  <Question { ...state } pushSingleAnswer={pushSingleAnswer} />
)}
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if it's possible to pass state and props to a component at the same time but now it seems so simple!